Roots of polynomials with reciprocal coefficients
Let $\mathbb{C}\ni a_0,\cdots,a_n\ne 0$ and define the polynomials
$$
p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k,\,p^{*}(x)= \sum_{k=0}^n a_k^{-1} x^k
$$
I'm interested in when the roots of $p$ and $p^{*}$ coincide; I think it occurs only for the trivial case $a_k = \pm 1$, i.e. when $a_k=a_{k}^{-1}$ for all $k$, but I'm not certain.
WLOG we can take $a_n=1$ since we are working over $\mathbb{C}$. For $n=0,1$ the problem is trivial. For $n=2$, the quadratic formula applied to $p$ and $p^{*}$ gives
$$x= \frac{-a_1\pm \sqrt{a_1^2-4a_0}}{2},\,x = \frac{-a_1\pm a_1^2\sqrt{\frac{1}{a_1^2}-\frac{4}{a_0}}}{2a_1^2}$$Equating the surd and non-surd parts (not sure if this is legal) gives
$$\begin{cases}
-a_1^3=-a_1\\
a_1^2\sqrt{a_1^2-4a_0}=a_1^2\sqrt{a_1^{-2}-4a_0^{-1}},
\end{cases}$$ from which the first equation gives $a_1=\pm1$ and then the second equation likewise gives $a_0=\pm1$, the expected solutions.
For $n=3$, I didn't solve it by hand, but I asked Mathematica to come up with 9 solutions and it only gave me 8, namely when $a_k=\pm1$, $0\le k\le2$, as I expected. Asking for solutions using the quartic formula timed out, so I have no data for the case $n=4$.
The trouble is not only that this isn't a rigorous proof, but that this method can't work for $n\ge 5$, as there is no general quintic or higher formula. Intuitively, I feel that the roots should only be the same when the coefficients are equal, though it would be quite remarkable if this is not true for some pair of polynomials. There is a concept of a reciprocal polynomial, though that's not what I'm after, as there the order of the exponents is reversed, whereas I want the reciprocals of the coefficients.

Two monic polynomials (i.e. with leading coefficient $=1$) have the same roots if and only if they have the same coefficients.

@MartinR is there a reference for that? Or am I missing an obvious fact?

It follows from the factorisation $f(x) = (x-x_1) \cdots (x-x_n)$ that every coefficient is a function of the roots. See also Vieta's formulas. – I am assuming that $p$ and $p^*$ have the same roots with same multplicities. If the multplicities are allowed to be different then things become more complicated.

@MartinR if you mentioned that and gave a sketch of a proof by induction, I would accept that as an answer.

$\text{Vieta's formula}$ states that
$$\sum_{1≤i_1<i_2<...<i_k≤n} \bigg(\prod_{j=1}^k r_{i_j}\bigg) =(-1)^k\frac{a_{n-k}}{a_n}$$
Where $r$ denotes the roots of the polynomial. For your question, as the roots stay same for both polynomials,
$$(-1)^k\frac{a_{n-k}}{a_n}=(-1)^k\frac{a_{n-k}^*}{a_n^*}$$
Now by your definition of $p^*(x)$, this equation becomes
$$\frac{a_{n-k}}{a_n}=\frac{a_n}{a_{n-k}}$$
This indicates $$(a_{n-k})^2-(a_n)^2=0\\
\implies a_{n-k}=-a_n \ \lor \ a_{n-k}=a_n\\
\implies -\frac 1a_n =a^*_{n-k} \ \lor \ \frac{1}{a_n} =a^*_{n-k}$$
If $p(x)$ and $p^*(x)$ have equal roots, then $$p(r_i)-p^*(r_i)=0\\
$$
We get two cases from here,
Case $1$
$$\bigg(a_n-\frac 1a_n\bigg)\sum_{j=0}^n r_i^j=0\implies a_n=±1$$
Case $2$
$$\bigg(a_n+\frac 1a_n\bigg)\sum_{j=0}^n r_i^j=0\implies a_n=±i$$
